# How to find an element on a page using Firefox without a timeout?

Tags: html, ruby, firefox, cucumber, capybara

When I attempt to find a an element, an element that is easily (relatively) fornd in chrome, times out in Firefox.

Here is an example

```
within('tr#blah') do
  fill_in('frm_blah', :with=>'foo')
end
```

This gets a response like...

```
    When I do the thing
# features/step_definitions/blah_steps.rb:13
  Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue
  in rbuf_fill'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fi
  ll'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readunt
  il'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readlin
  e'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_statu
  s_line'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in t
  ransport_request'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_
  request'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in r
  equest'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
  ./features/step_definitions/blah_steps.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <to
  p (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/blah_steps.rb:20:in `/^I select "(.*?)"$/'
  features\blah.feature:17:in `When I fill in blah'
```

Any ideas for making Firefox less angry?

Comment: Those are not browser errors, they're Rails errors. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: except timeouts do not occur with chromedriver, just the native Firefox

Comment: Are you sure any of the 3 lines you provided are in blah_steps.rb:13 ?